# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo Application Crashes upon launch

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Button btnShowLocation=null;

        // GPSTracker class
        GPSTracker gps;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshowloc);

            // show location button click event
            btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {       
                    // create class object
                    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                    // check if GPS enabled       
                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                        // \n is for new line
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                    }else{
                        // can't get location
                        // GPS or Network is not enabled
                        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    This is My main activty claass

    package com.example.locateus;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

        private final Context mContext;

        // flag for GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

        // flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        // flag for GPS status
        boolean canGetLocation = false;

        Location location; // location
        double latitude; // latitude
        double longitude; // longitude

        // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

        // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

        // Declaring a Location Manager
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        public GPSTracker(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
            getLocation();
        }

        public Location getLocation() {
            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return location;
        }

        /**
         * Stop using GPS listener
         * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
         * */
        public void stopUsingGPS(){
            if(locationManager != null){
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            }       
        }

        /**
         * Function to get latitude
         * */
        public double getLatitude(){
            if(location != null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            // return latitude
            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         * */
        public double getLongitude(){
            if(location != null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            // return longitude
            return longitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
         * @return boolean
         * */
        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        /**
         * Function to show settings alert dialog
         * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
         * */
        public void showSettingsAlert(){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

            // On pressing Settings button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                 //   Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                   // mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }

      @Override
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

      @Override
     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

      @Override
     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

      @Override
     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

      @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
     }

    }
```

After running the application , the application crashes upon start up, i have checked the liabaries  and checking for correct build java path for the project properties , still i cannot find  the solution to this . Please help me.

Comment: Post the logcat error.

Comment: Probably an NPE at `btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener()`. Un-comment the `findViewById()` line, and make sure the Button is in the layout.

Comment: This is the error shown at the logCat..........05-08 12:23:26.280: D/AndroidRuntime(1583): Shutting down VM
05-08 12:23:26.300: W/dalvikvm(1583): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
05-08 12:23:26.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 12:23:26.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.locateus/com.example.gpstracking.MainActivity}:

Comment: Try the solution provided by Mike M.

Comment: try to un-comment this code btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation); becz you have to find button before setOnClickListener().

Comment: I have done that, and i have checked and set the correct values in the ActivityMain.xml file and the string.xml files to as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will crash:

```
//  btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

The variable `btnShowLocation` will not have a value, and you must give it one.

Uncomment the line and make sure that `R.id.btnShowLocation` has a valid value.

Comment: I have get a default value for the button like this ....Button btnShowLocation=null; and I have uncomment that line as said but still it doesn't run

Comment: Now I have changed the code as you recommended but yet it is not working

Comment: The answer to your original problem is here. If you want your code reviewed we have a site for that: CodeReview. If you want to ask another question, please do, but then provide additional details of your new problem. This is not a good place for assisted debugging.